# Google Play Advertising ID? New Google Play Developer Policies?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-advertising-id

Google has updated the Google `Play Developer Policies`. I am not getting the ADs section: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html#ADID.

I have apps which contains Ads by AdMob & Google Play Services, currently I'm seeing there is no rising of revenue or request count in my account since 24hrs. Don't know what is going wrong.

Any idea what I need to do? How to use this Advertising ID and AdMob together?